# How to group the data in factorplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

```
sns.set_style("white")
g = sns.factorplot(x="CREATED_AT1", y="count", hue='KW', 
data=df_kw_mentions, size=5, aspect=2, palette="GnBu_d")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
g.set(xlabel='Year-Month', ylabel='Count')
```

[image]

Since the x-axis has data for Year-month. It would like to group the data as in combine 4 months for better display. Is it possible to do it with factorplot alone?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. How would you like the plot to look like exactly? Is there any specific reason to use a factorplot here? (It does not seem to be the type of plot best suited for the data). Also provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I think you need to have a look for the pandas resample - how to group datetime type to Q. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html